# Получить данные из xml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, beautiful-soup, bs4

Есть xml:

```xml
<record>
<FIELD.700>
<SUBFIELD.3>10005847</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Мартыненко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>А. В.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.700>
<FIELD.1105>
Статья в журнале
</FIELD.1105>
</record>
<record>
<FIELD.700>
<SUBFIELD.3>10005016</SUBFIELD.3><SUBFIELD.A>Яценко</SUBFIELD.A><SUBFIELD.B>А. С.</SUBFIELD.B>
</FIELD.700>
<FIELD.1105>
Статья в журнале
</FIELD.1105>
</record>
```

Я пытаюсь получить данные:

```
def get_statuses(record) -> str:
    statuses = record.find_all("FIELD.1105")
    return statuses

def get_write():
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

    for record in root.select('record'):
        statuses = get_statuses(record)
        print(statuses)

a = get_write()
print(a)
```

Но почему-то получаю только `None`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём моя ошибка?

Желаемый результат:

```
Статья в журнале
Статья в журнале
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Измените функцию так:

```
def get_statuses(record) -> str:
    statuses = record.find("field.1105")
    return statuses.text.strip()
```

Comment: gil9red@, огромное спасибо!!! Всё работает!!!